# At which stripe event should I update my db to grant subscriber access

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, stripe-payments, webhooks

I have a SaaS MERN app which is using Stripe for subscriptions. I'm using the new checkout feature of Stripe to handle all the payments. I have the stripe CLI installed to see the events that occur when a subscription is made. I have a few questions regarding the events that are emitted and how to handle them in my stripe webhook.

1. Which event below indicate that the payment was successful so that I can update my database.
2. Why is it that the `payment_intent.succeeded` occurs before `payment_intent.created`.
3. Why is a `customer.subscription.updated` event happening (I'm assuming it should just be the `customer.subscription.created` event that should occur on first purchase)
4. I use the `customer.subscription.updated` event in my webhook to allow customers to turn autoRenewal on and off. Because the `customer.subscription.updated` event is also shot off at initial payment when subscribing, how can I differentiate what to do as the same event is fired off in both cases.
5. This is not as important, but if anyone knows what that `POST` error is at the bottom, I would appreciate some insight. [EDIT] I fixed this by moving my `res.status(200).json({received: true})` further up my code. Initially it was placed at the very end of my webhook, so I think it was timing out.

[image: screenshot of events fired off when checkout session is completed.]

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you specifically want to provision the subscription on successful payment, then you should listen for `payment_intent.succeeded`
2. Stripe doesn't guarantee the order of webhook events, it's possible to receive them out of order: https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/best-practices#event-ordering
3. The subscription's `status` would be updated to show that the latest invoice was successfully paid, which triggers and update event
4. You probably want to use `invoice.upcoming` instead: https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types?lang=java#event_types-invoice.upcoming
5. You'd have to debug this on your end to see where it came from. Looks like perhaps your local server wasn't running and so the Stripe CLI couldn't forward on the webhook event.